# To format all the Decimal Nodes to European Amount formatting

Tags: xslt

I have an XML which has Decimal field which need to formatted to European Currency format.
The Current its having US format.

```
-<Envelope>
 -<Body>
  -<getPriceRecommendationResponse>
   -<status>
     <statusCode>Success</statusCode>
    </status>
   -<priceRecommendation>
     <tssArticleNumber>Item Number1234</tssArticleNumber>
     <compoundCode>N123</compoundCode>
     <compoundGroupCodeBucket>A</compoundGroupCodeBucket>
     <compoundCodeBucket>N123 & others</compoundCodeBucket>
     <qualityIndexCode>-</qualityIndexCode>
     <qualityIndexBucket>Std Quality</qualityIndexBucket>
     <weight>66.0341</weight>
     <weightGroupBucket>BT 123.1234 and 12345.1234</weightGroupBucket>
     <weightIsValidBucket>YES</weightIsValidBucket>
     <subGroupCode>PT</subGroupCode>
     <subGroupCodeBucket>7:B03</subGroupCodeBucket>
     <stockDistinction>MTS</stockDistinction>
     <productIdBucket>PT0401450-T46N</productIdBucket>
     <referencePrice>42.076</referencePrice>
     <averageQuantity>9</averageQuantity>
     <quantityAdjustments>0.96</quantityAdjustments>
     <highDV>2.123789</highDV>
     <averageDV>1.25141</averageDV>
     <lowDV>0.79983</lowDV>
     <additionalAdjustmentsTotal>1</additionalAdjustmentsTotal>
     <highPrice>19876.9124796544</highPrice>
     <averagePrice>12345.5481540736</averagePrice>
     <lowPrice>123344567.3075011968</lowPrice>
   </priceRecommendation>
  </getPriceRecommendationResponse>
 </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Please help me with an xslt which can format all the Decimal Nodes in the XML.

The below is an xslt i am already using. I am expecting a similar one. Thanks

```
//this has been taken from a Microsoft knowledgebase aricle and strips out the
//namespaces from an XML message using a style sheet
XslTransform :=  XslTransform.XslTransform;
XMLStyleSheet := XMLStyleSheet.XmlDocument;
XMLStyleSheet.InnerXml(
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'+
'<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">'+
'<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>' +
'<xsl:template match="@*|node()">'+
'<xsl:copy>'+
'<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>'+
'</xsl:copy>'+
'</xsl:template>'+
'<xsl:template match="'+OldNode+'">'+
'<xsl:variable name="oldNode" select="'+OldNode+'"/>' +
'<xsl:variable name="newNodeXml">' +
'<xsl:element name="'+NewNode+'">' +
'<xsl:copy-of select="$oldNode/@*|node()"/>' +
'<xsl:copy-of select="$oldNode/child::*"/>' +
'<xsl:copy-of select="$oldNode/@*"/>' +
'</xsl:element>' +
'</xsl:variable>' +
'<xsl:copy-of select="msxml:node-set($newNodeXml)"/>' +
'</xsl:template>' +
'</xsl:stylesheet>'
);
XslTransform.Load(XMLStyleSheet);
writer := writer.StringWriter();
XslTransform.Transform(Source, nullXsltArgumentList, writer);
Destination := Destination.XmlDocument;
Destination.InnerXml(writer.ToString());
```

Thank you guys for your response. I hope i can make the things more clear to you. The European format is "," for Decimal separator and "." for Digit Grouping. Whereas US have the reverse. For example 1,000.156 in US and 1.000,156 for Europe. Yes Rnet i have tried the decimal-format its working fine, but the problem here is i need to use it multiple times for the Fields. I want an XSLT which change the format for all the decimal fields at once. I hope you got my point

Thank you Michael, I have tried your code but getting an error. 
**A call to System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform.Load failed with this message: Expression must evaluate to a node-set.**

I have changed the code little bit given by Michael, but still getting the same error.

```
'<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="decimalformat.xsl"?>'+
'<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">'+
'<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>'+
'<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>'+
'<xsl:decimal-format name="eu" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="." />'+
'<!-- identity transform -->'+
'<xsl:template match="@*|node()">'+
'    <xsl:copy>'+
'         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>'+
'    </xsl:copy>'+
'</xsl:template>'+
'<xsl:template match="*[number()=number()]">'+
'    <xsl:copy>'+
'        <xsl:value-of select=translate("format-number(., '#.##0,##########', 'eu'), ',', '.')" />'+
'    </xsl:copy>'+
'</xsl:template>'+
'</xsl:stylesheet>'
```

In my application its not working. I have found a similar post here http://mikeschinkel.com/blog/gettingpastthexslterrorexpressionmustevaluatetoanodeset/#comment-484235

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(., '#.##0,##########', 'eu')" />
```

I am getting the error if i include the above code. i have tried it this way as well.

```
<xsl:value-of select=translate("format-number(., '#.##0,##########', 'eu'), ',', '.')" />
```

Comment: What is "European Currency format"? Please post the required output code.

Comment: Searching the web gives, <xsl:decimal-format> and format-number(), did you try them? http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_decimal-format.asp

Comment: Thank you guys for your response. I hope i can make the things more clear to you. The European format is "," for Decimal separator and "." for Digit Grouping. Whereas US have the reverse. For example 1,000.156 in US and 1.000,156 for Europe. Yes Rnet i have tried the decimal-format its working fine, but the problem here is i need to use it multiple times for the Fields. I want an XSLT which change the format for all the decimal fields at once. I hope you got my point

Comment: Do not post vital information in comments. Please update (edit) your post instead.

Comment: @PrajeeshNair "*I am sure the Problem is in this piece of code*". I am sure it's not. As I already said, you can see it working here:http://xsltransform.net/bFDb2C4

Comment: "In my application it's not working" - then, the problem lies with your application - the code is fine and does not produce the error you show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the problem here is i need to use it multiple times for the Fields. I
>   want an XSLT which change the format for all the decimal fields at
>   once.

This could be accomplished by a template that matches only elements containing strictly numeric values, for example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:decimal-format name="eu" decimal-separator=',' grouping-separator='.' />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[number()=number()]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(., '#.##0,##########', 'eu')" />
    </xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**:

1. This will not work with your input, because it contains an unescaped ampersand character;
2. This will **not** process elements that contain numbers as part of a string, e.g:
    `<weightGroupBucket>BT 123.1234 and 12345.1234</weightGroupBucket>`
3. This has nothing to do with currency.

Comment: Thank you Michael, I have tried your code but getting an error. 

A call to System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform.Load failed with this message: Expression must evaluate to a node-set.                                                I have changed the code a little bit still not able to solve the error.

Comment: @PrajeeshNair The error is not due to my code - see it working here:http://xsltransform.net/bFDb2C4